# use a function to execute another function (with a variable amount of parameters) Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Im trying to create a function that can repeat another function with variable amount of paramemters. However I am only getting the reference to anonymous arrow function rather than the return value of the function (func) I am trying to pass in. I've tried func(). but that seems

```ts
const testFunction1 = (x:number,y:number) => {
    return {x,y}
}
const testFunction2 = (foo:string, bar:string, baz:string) => {
    return {foo, bar, baz}
}

const repeatFunction = (num: number, func: () => unknown) => {

    const returnValues: Array<(unknown)> = []

    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        returnValues.push(func())
    }

    return returnValues
}
const result = repeatFunction(5, () => testFunction1(4,5))
console.log(result)
```

Whats really weird is that when I look into the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BiBXMwoEtwEYYF4YAKADwC4wUBbAI3gCcAaATwurvoEoCA%20GAbwBQMETHrwoKemAEkWAX0GLQkWAmRoM2MACYCxAGYgQZaPUxgA5oxg0AhvVNRzVm-YBeTl5e74%20Q0TEJKRl%20IxA3B0j3RUVBFWgggAd4OyhUdCxwfSJKKjIYPI4bA00Col8%20NABrMBAAdzBKgUFhUQTYcUlpADU7ABsURAKAQXp6O2YAHiIausbOPkIAbQBdVsCjemJ%20iRhMfQAGAG59mCnC6lPMAGob7gDA0S6QvsHEADoklAgACyJSugKpw2iI4oEXtIgt0wG8hhAlPFwIlxBAUP1YIRxCk0hktOAiABWGwVXhwRDpTRZMA4IgAFkYhM4IISIF2H36IEsRFR6KgnCAA) this seems to be working fine. But when I use my editor and debugger I get the following error

***Error***
Uncaught TypeError: func is not a function

Comment: _"Uncaught TypeError: func is not a function"_ is actually a runtime error, not a compile time error. So you have to trace where the value of `func` is coming from in your code to figure out why it's not a function. How does your code differs from what's in that playground?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not passing this function `() => testFunction1(4,5)`
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9lUw.png)